# How to set persistent variables in current session with Powershell Functions

Tags: function, powershell, variables

I just started writing functions with Powershell and it got me thinking that I could create a function that would set a number of variables I often use instead of having to start all the one-liners I'm already used to with a full query every time.  I could set those variables in my PS Profile but it would cause the data to become less and less up-to-date as time goes by and I sometimes keep the same session open for days at a time.

Example :

Instead of going :

```
PS C:\>Get-ADComputer -Filter {whatever -like "*this*that*"} | ForEach-Object {more code} | and so on
```

I could go :

```
PS C:\>$servers | ForEach-Object {more code} | and so on
```

However, as every one here probably knows, when I execute a function in which variables are set, as soon as the function ends, the variables set in it are deleted from the console's memory.  I know I can dot source my function but in some cases, although a variable does exist in my session after doing

```
PS C:\>. Do-Something
```

it's not returning any value but a blank line instead.

So how can I set a variable inside a function that will remain in my current session after said function has been executed ?

Comment: Read [Get-Help about_scopes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_scopes?view=powershell-5.1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `$Global:variable` instead `$variable` inside your function.

Comment: Exactly what I needed to know (^^,)  Thank you.

Someone sent a link earlier explaining scopes ; that was helpful as well.

Answer (score 0):

As above in your script you can use pattern as follows

```
("ABC", "DEF", "GHI", "JKL") |
%{
    Set-Variable -Name "$($_)" -Value 1 -Scope Global 
}
```

and then after script has finished in console:

```
$ABC * $DEF
$GHI + $JKL
```